# understand what is the GOP size (i-frame/p-frame ratio) in a video

Tags: actionscript-3, ffmpeg, video-encoding, codec, mencoder

i am doing stuffs with a video in action script and i need to seek a video to acertain frame. according to the reference, using NetStream.seek i can seek only to the nearest k-frame:

```
Seeks the keyframe (also called an I-frame in the video industry) closest to the specified location. The keyframe is placed at an offset, in seconds, from the beginning of the stream.

Video streams are usually encoded with two types of frames, keyframes (or I-frames) and P-frames. A keyframe contains an entire image, while a P-frame is an interim frame that provides additional video information between keyframes. A video stream typically has a keyframe every 10-50 frames.
```

and so i need to understand how many p-frame and i-frame there are in a video encoded in .f4v format.

i am on mac and on ubuntu, i don't care about the tool to use (mayebe some ffmpeg/mencoder call should be perfect), any advice?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Adobe Media Encoder, you can set custom presets under the video tab / advanced settings.

check set keyframe distance
then set it to 1 frames

this should generate a high key frame count.

hope this helps.